# Tree structure: Best way to find element and save chain of parent elements

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

I have a JSONObject, which could have JSONArray of same same type children. I would like to iterate over it, find the element which I need and save the chain of parent elements (e.g. found element is the child of this element, this element is the child of next element, next element is the child of root).

**Currently here is my naive implementation:**

```
private boolean found;

private void searchNode(List<JSONObject> chain, 
                       JSONObject rootNode, JSONObject desiredFrame) {

    if (found)
        return;

    JSONArray children = rootNode.getJSONArray("frames");

    chain.add(rootNode);

    for (int i = 0; i < children.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject currentNode = children.getJSONObject(i);

        if (currentNode.equals(desiredNode)) {
            found = true;
            chain.add(currentNode);
            return;
        }

        searchNode(chain, currentNode, desiredNode);

        if (!found)
            chain.remove(currentNode);
    }
```

**What problems can I see:**

1. I am not sure it will work well :)
2. This implementation is not obvious, It's not clean code.
3. I am using class field, probably I could avoid that usage

This structure could be named tree, but this one is not binary.

Comment: Could you provide an Example of how the JSON looks like and what exactly you want to extract from that?

Comment: I think this implementation is just fine: depth first search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some potential problems with code:

- you can replace shared flag `found` with result of `searchNode`.
- you are comparing a `JSONObject` for equals. I would recommend to use `Predicate` to check is it proper node or not.
- `rootNode.getJSONArray("frames")` can returns `null` or empty array, but you never check it.
- Also you can use `Stack<>` instead of `List<>` to track a path. It can simplify your algorithm.

Example:

```
private static boolean searchNode(Stack<JSONObject> chain,
                                  JSONObject currentNode, Predicate<JSONObject> condition) throws Exception {

    if (condition.test(currentNode)) {
        chain.push(currentNode);
        return true;
    }

    JSONArray children = currentNode.getJSONArray("frames");
    if (children == null) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < children.length(); i++) {
        if (searchNode(chain, children.getJSONObject(i), condition)) {
            chain.push(currentNode);
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a better algorithm to search for your object.

You don't have to maintain a found field or pass your chain as a parameter.

Instead you use the return values of your recursive calls to build the chain once you find the object

```
List<JSONObject> search(JSONObject node, JSONObject searchTerm) {
    if (node.equals(searchTerm)) {
        List<JSONObject> chain = new List<>();
        chain.add(node);
        return chain;
    } else {
        List chain = new Collections.emptyList();
        for (JSONObject child: node.getJSONArray("frames")) {
            chain = search(child, searchTerm);
            if (chain.length > 0) {
                chain.add(0, node);
                break;
            }
        }
        return chain;
    }
}
```

Comment: just to do that right - you should add chain,add(0, parent), but not child - you did that before.

Comment: Good catch. Thanks.